Excel VBA making the dialogsheet appears in the center of the screen
Below is the code I have that will generate a popup box requesting user to select the worksheet they want. But the issue is that the popup box will always appear at different location when it pops up is there a way to make it appear in the center of the worksheet? Or is there any other method to generate a popup box for user to select?
        Const ColItems  As Long = 20
        Const LetterWidth As Long = 20
        Const HeightRowz As Long = 30
        Const SheetID As String = "__SheetSelection"
         
        Dim Y%, TopPos%, iSet%, optCols%, intLetters%, optMaxChars%, optLeft%
        Dim wsDlg As DialogSheet, objOpt As OptionButton, optCaption$, objSheet As Object
        optCaption = "": Y = 0
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets(SheetID).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Err.Clear
         
        Set wsDlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add
        With wsDlg
        .Name = SheetID
        .Visible = xlSheetHidden
        iSet = 0: optCols = 0: optMaxChars = 0: optLeft = 100: TopPos = 40
         
        For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If objSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        Y = Y + 1
         
        If Y Mod ColItems = 1 Then
        optCols = optCols + 1
        TopPos = 45
        optLeft = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth)
        optMaxChars = 0
        End If
         
        intLetters = Len(objSheet.Name)
        If intLetters > optMaxChars Then optMaxChars = intLetters
        iSet = iSet + 1
        .OptionButtons.Add optLeft, TopPos, intLetters * LetterWidth, 16
        .OptionButtons(iSet).Text = objSheet.Name
        TopPos = TopPos + 14
         
        End If
        Next objSheet
         
        If Y > 0 Then
         
        With .DialogFrame
        .Height = Application.Max(80, WorksheetFunction.Min(iSet, ColItems) * HeightRowz + 10)
        .Width = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth)
        .Caption = "Select sheet"
        End With
         
        If .Show = True Then
        For Each objOpt In wsDlg.OptionButtons
        If objOpt.Value = xlOn Then
        optCaption = objOpt.Caption
        Exit For
        End If
        Next objOpt
        End If
         
        If optCaption = "" Then
        MsgBox "You did not select a worksheet.", 48, "Cannot continue"
        Exit Sub
        Else
        
        Set ws2 = Worksheets(optCaption)
         
        End If
         
        End If
         
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         
        End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'ws2_name = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a worksheet", Title:="Select Worksheet")
    'Set ws2 = Worksheets(ws2_name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled...", vbInformation
    Else


As far as I know, you cannot control the position of a dialog. You can if you use a Userform.
